# How is Area 51 initial reputation gained?

Tags: support, reputation, area-51

I am a new to the Stack Exchange family and I got to see Area 51 - the staging area.

But, for any action I need to do (either ask a question, answering, proposing, etc.) in that except for the editing of tag wikis needs at least 5 reputation. What are options for me to gain that initial reputations in Area  51?

- Can it be through some activities in Area 51 itself?
- Do I need to wait for the association bonus of 100 reputations to be credited once I make a 200+ reputation in any of the Stack Exchange sites?
- Is some other option existing, like reputation sharing with some other sites in this family?

Comment: confirm your email... that gives you +50.

Comment: yes. it helped. i got my start in Area51. Thanks for @yoda

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Earn 200 reputation on any Q&A site in the Stack Exchange network to get an automatic one-time +100 "association bonus" on all your associated accounts.
- On Area 51 specifically, you can verify your email address for an additional +50 reputation.

This will give you 151 reputation, with which you'll be able to perform most of the basic actions on Area 51.