# Cannot comment or ask on Area 51 due to insufficient reputation

Tags: support, reputation, area-51, privileges

I just joined Area 51 and noticed a strange bug on the meta: Although I have 50 reputation, it still says that I can't comment on the meta because I don't have 5 reputation. I also therefore can't ask questions because you need 15 Area 51 Discussions reputation to ask a question. Why might this be happening?
Pictures:
[image]

Comment: Looks like you only have 1 reputation on Area 51

Comment: To get 50 you need to [verify your email](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135418/152859)

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks forgot about that :-)

Comment: Yeah, question is why OP think he got 50 reputation...

Comment: Probably read something about the email verification but didn't actually do it... at a guess

Comment: @Cai - I did click the link. I have now added images of the problem.

Comment: What is the link to the user profile you're using in that screenshot? I see only 1 rep and a different avatar (but there's been some funky stuff going on with those so that may not mean anything)

Comment: @Cai http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/161945/ethan-chapman?tab=stats

Comment: Hmm, looks like you have multiple accounts (not 100% certain that is the issue, but it's *an* issue). You should use the [contact form](http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) and ask to merge your accounts [1](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/160735/ethan-chapman) & [2](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/161945/ethan-chapman)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you only have 1 reputation on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/160735/ethan-chapman). Reputation is earned on a per-site basis and does not carry over, so you need to earn enough reputation on Area 51 itself.

It's worth noting that you have 199 reputation on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/161585/ethan-chapman). Once you hit 200 reputation on *any site* you get a +100 association bonus on *every site*, so all you need to do is earn +1 on Arqade and you will get the bonus on your Area51 account.

Also, on Area 51 (as opposed to other sites) you can verify your email address for an additional +50 reputation (as mentioned in the [FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation)).

You can read more about how reputation works here:

- **[How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)**

Comment: Just earlier today it said that I had 50 rep from the association bonus. Still, I'll work on getting to 200 on Arqade.

Comment: Did you confirm your email for Area 51? If so you should have the +50 from that

Comment: Yes, I did. I retried the email link, and the same thing happened.

Comment: One way to get a few quick rep points on Arqade to push you over 200 is to get a few post edits accepted. Find a few questions and/or answers that have poor grammar, spelling, or capitalization and fix them.

Comment: The association bonus apparently does not carry over to Area 51

Comment: It does. [You have 101 rep](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/160735/ethan-chapman). As I said you have multiple accounts. Use the contact form to get them merged.